# In app email with two emails

Tags: ios, email

I am making an app and I have an in app email but I need to have two emails in it heres is my code.

```
- (IBAction)openMail: (id)sender {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage,2.0);


MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"calf@winrocspi.com", nil ]];
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Board Count"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:self.AddNotesTextField.text isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"attachment.png"];
    [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
newmedia = YES;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Simply add the 2nd email to the recipients array.

Comment: [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"calf@winrocspi.com", @"SECOND_EMAIL@winrocspi.com", nil ]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the mails in `setToRecipients:`

```
- (IBAction)openMail: (id)sender {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);

NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage,2.0);


MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    //here you should add another email
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"calf@winrocspi.com",@"putanother@email.com", nil ]]; 


    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Board Count"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:self.AddNotesTextField.text isHTML:NO];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"attachment.png"];
    [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
newmedia = YES;
}
```

Comment: if this answer helped you.You can accept this answer it will help others to find solution